# HOW TO PRINT "THAT'S IT!" IN PHP? WITH DOUBLE AND SINGLE QUOTATIONS?

Tags: php

I want to print "that's it!" Exactly as same with double and single quotations in php? Can anyone have solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to escape the single quote with a back slash

```
 echo '"that\'s it!"';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll post something different because I like them and it think it's often missed or unknown by less experienced programmers.

HereDoc/NowDoc

```
//HereDoc works like " for variables 
echo <<<TXT
"that's it!"
TXT;
```

The `TXT` tag can be anything that follows the same rules as variable names (`\w+`, and must start with Alpha), and the ending one must be on it's own line with "ABSOULTLY" nothing else besides `;` (which can be omitted in arrays), nothing else not even whitespaces.

```
//NowDoc works like ' for variables
echo <<<'TXT'
"that's it!"
TXT;
```

It's often overlooked, as it's not documented in any really visible place, it's the third example on the string type page on PHP.net.  Then after a bunch of scrolling you'll find the `Nowdoc` part, the only real difference is how they treat variables, as I mentioned.

http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: <<<. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.
>
> The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line. Also, the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore.
>   Warning
>
> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including macOS. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.
>
> If this rule is broken and the closing identifier is not "clean", it will not be considered a closing identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper closing identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a parse error will result at the last line.

This is also common in other languages besides PHP (with minor variations), and it's the cleanest way (for larger amounts of text, think HTML, JavaScript and a mix of those and PHP).

```
$selector = 'a.foobar';
echo <<<HTML
  <script type="text/javascript">
       ;( function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
            "use strict";
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('tr.foobar').css('display', 'none');//singe quotes are fine
                 $("div.foobar").css("display", "none");//double quotes are too
                 $({$selector}).css('display', "none");//we can even mix them up if we want.
                  //we can use PHP variable like {$selector}, even these 
                  //comments become comments in the JS.
                  //if that wasn't enough, most IDE's treat them like HTML
                  //so they are not greyed out, but nicely colored!
            });
       } ) ( jQuery, window, document );
  </script>
HTML;
```

And this would work just fine, even the `{$selector}` would be replaced by PHP, the `{}` are optional except for method calls (unless they changed that).  I put them in by habit because it colors them better in my IDE. Which is excatly how PHP treats variables in "normal" double quoted strings. (variable interpolation) except here we can use both types of quotes any way we want to...

If you do ever put one in an array it will only work this way (without the `;`):

```
   $a = [
<<<TXT
    sometext
TXT
   , "something else",
   1,
   2,
   'etc..'
 ];
```

Other languages that use them (linked to the PHP section)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#PHP

> In computing, a here document *(here-document, here-text, heredoc, hereis, here-string or here-script)* is a file literal or input stream literal: it is a section of a source code file that is treated as if it were a separate file. The term is also used for a form of multiline string literals that use similar syntax, preserving line breaks and other whitespace (including indentation) in the text.

The important thing is it does not use the quotes to define the string, so you are free to use them however you want, with no escaping.

**One last thing I happened to notice** from the PHP documentation that i never really read before.

> the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is `\n` on UNIX systems, including macOS

Maybe someone else knows, but I am not sure how important this bit really is.  I program on a Windows Desktop `\r\n`, and then use the same exact files on a Linux server `\n` and Have Never 1 time had an issue with what that says. I do use editors though like Eclipse PDT, so it may default to the `\n` even on windows.  But I have never had an issue on either one....

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the ways that works without escaping is as follows:

```
echo('"'."that'".'s it!"');
```

Comment: While true, this is not easy to decipher at quick glance.  As mentioned by ArtisticPhoenix above, I'd recommend using a nowdoc.